# How can I make a black glass pass light through it?

Tags: rendering, glass

I want to render a black colored glass and make light pass through it. But if I give the glass *Nodes* and *Transparency Nodes* it changes the color of the glass into transparently white. How can I keep the glass black and make light pass through it?

I don’t have a photo of it, but how it be done?

Comment: Reference image of desired result would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For Cycles, that can be disabling shadow ray visibility:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the light path node's camera output to control a mix shader's factor input. Then plug your glass shader into the second input and a transparent bsdf into the first input. This will make the object visible to the camera, but invisible to other surfaces, so effectively light will pass through it.

Comment: Thank You . I got the result it was very helpful